# Why would a Spring Boot library be unable to add its dependencies to the parent app's classpath?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, thymeleaf, dependency-management

Our goal is to write a Spring Boot library that can be depended on by a Spring Boot app.

If included as a dependency, our library is intended to serve a page constructed using a `Thymeleaf` template from a controller it creates.

In order to do this, our library depends on the following Spring libraries in turn:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.yaml:snakeyaml'
    api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot'
    api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.9.1'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-testing:3.0.4.RELEASE'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
}
```

Our library jar builds just fine.  However, when we attempt to test it using a demo project that includes our library as a dependency, the application context cannot load, since our library code can no longer see code it depends on.  The error message is as follows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

The 'SpringTemplateEngine' is a class that should be included in our classpath via the dependency on 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf' above.

We've played with the build script, switching `implementation` for `api` at various points, importing packages directly instead of using 'starter's, etc.

One thing that 'solves the problem' is to just import `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` in the demo project.  Then, our library works flawlessly.  However, this is not how dependencies should work!  Our consumers should not have to depend on us plus our dependencies to use our library.  We've somehow failed at transitivity.

- What are the ways this can have happened?
- What are we missing about how dependency chaining works in Spring Boot Java libraries?

Comment: Is the error thrown when running tests?

Comment: @Andronicus A similar error with what we believe to be the same root cause, yes.

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ITemplateResolver
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
 ... 121 more`

Comment: Have you tried to use `api` for both dependencies in library and library dependency in demo?

Comment: @itwasntme Thank you, but that's not possible to try; the demo is not itself a library, but an application, and so its Gradle plugin doesn't have the 'api' dependency configuration.

Comment: Adding `java-library` plugin doesn't make it automatically a library. The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53725937/how-to-use-gradle-api-dependency) quotes and links the documentation where the last quoted sentence says "but also as soon as you have external dependencies". Why not require the library users to apply that plugin and import library as `api`?

Comment: How is the demo application depending on the library - is it a multi-project or a binary dependency (e.g. deployed to a Maven repository)? And are you using the Spring Boot _plugin_ in the library?